# Updating the D3 selection of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building an interactive scatter-line plot, and I am having trouble updating the selection of circles (the data points SEEM to work okay, but I cannot be sure, as the behavior is somewhat erratic). When I create an initial plot, the dots and lines appear ok, but after clicking a node and it gets removed, I cannot reset the selection. To be more specific, the variable "i" (which in my understanding gives the index of the object in selection) remains bound to the initial selection. The code is below:

```
        function mousedownCircle(d, i) {
            console.log(i);
            circles[0][i].remove();
            dataset.splice(i, 1);
            circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataset);
            line_obj.attr("d", valueline(dataset));
            d3.event.stopPropagation();
        }

        // Create Circles
        var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")  // Add circle svg
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return xScale(d[0]);  // Circle's X
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {  // Circle's Y
                return yScale(d[1]);
            })
            .attr("r", radius)  // radius
            .on("click", mousedownCircle); // click callback
```

The main idea is to be able to remove both the circle and data point. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You don't need to remove the circle: just remove the data point and use an "update" + "exit" selection. However, for anyone here help you, you'll have to post a working code, with your data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to `d3` is to follow a proper `enter`, `update`, `exit` pattern.  I typically will wrap it into a function that I can call regardless of the action to "redraw" my visualization.  From looking at your code snippet, a proper function would look like:

```
function update() {

  // Create Circles
  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset);

  circles.exit().remove(); // remove the ones exiting

  circles = circles
    .enter() // Add circle to svg
    .append("circle")
    .merge(circles); // this is the update + enter selection

  circles // update circles
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d[0]); // Circle's X
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { // Circle's Y
      return yScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("r", 40) // radius
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .on("click", mousedownCircle); // click callback
}
```

Your `mousedownCircle` function then becomes as simple as:

```
function mousedownCircle(d, i) {
    dataset.splice(i, 1);
    update();
}
```

Running example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function mousedownCircle(d, i) {
      dataset.splice(i, 1);
      update();
    }

    var w = 400,
      h = 400;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h);

    var dataset = [
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h],
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h],
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h],
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h],
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h],
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h]
    ];

    update();

    function update() {

      // Create Circles
      var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset);

      circles.exit().remove();

      circles = circles
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .merge(circles); // Add circle svg
        
      circles
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d[0]; // Circle's X
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { // Circle's Y
          return d[1];
        })
        .attr("r", 40) // radius
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .on("click", mousedownCircle); // click callback

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Response to Comments**

The most direct way to do what you are after would be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function mousedownCircle(d, i) {
      d3.select(this).remove();
    }

    var w = 400,
      h = 400;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h);

    var dataset = [
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h],
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h],
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h],
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h],
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h],
      [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h]
    ];


    // Create Circles
    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d[0]; // Circle's X
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { // Circle's Y
        return d[1];
      })
      .attr("r", 40) // radius
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .on("click", mousedownCircle); // click callback
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I would bother you for a small update as well - the intial idea was to be "optimal" in my execution and not update the circles that are unaffected by the click, just the one removed/changed. does this make sense and how would I target just one circle? Or is this bad practice?